# PHP/Regex replace inch character with proper quotation marks

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I want to replace inch characters `"` with proper German quotation marks `„example“`.

An example String would be:

```
$string = `Mein Name ist "Joseph"`
```

I tried

```
str_replace("\"", '„', $string)
```

but of course it's replacing all of the inch characters with the same quotation mark

```
Mein Name ist „Joseph„
```

So I guess I need a regex to somehow replace the inch character *before* a word with `„` and the inch character *after* the same word with `“` to get the result

```
Mein Name ist „Joseph“
```

Despite reading how regex works, I can't really figure out how to achieve that.

Any tips would be gladly welcomed, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
$re = '/("([^"]*)")/';
$str = 'Mein Name ist "Joseph"';
$subst = '„$2“';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

Check out, [`preg_replace` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Made [this on `regex.com`](https://regex101.com/r/fdlO3Z/1)

Comment: Wow, that's great, thanks very much and also for the links! I will try to decipher the regex on regex.com  Thx again!

Comment: You don't need to enclose all your pattern between parenthesis, only one capture group is useful. Also you don't need the m modifier.

Comment: @ToE was there anything could be added in my post (you unmarked as answer) ?

Comment: @aXuser264 I'm sorry, I thought I marked your post as answer, must be that I unmarked it by accident when I upvoted your answer. Thanks again for your help with the code!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I used a regex to replace the first " and then replaced everything else with the second character.

```
$string = 'Mein Name ist "Joseph"';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/ "/';
$patterns[1] = '/^"/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[1] = ' „';
$replacements[0] = '^„';
$str = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
$str = str_replace("\"", '“', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the accepted answer and it worked. Thanks though for your effort, Moradnejad 